# Safari 3 and 4 are not agreeing with me for once, need help with my css and centering plus another weird thing

Tags: css, xhtml, jquery-plugins

Hey I am completely lost with this one.

Basically the website i'm working on here: **[Home page](http://deesideinteriors.co.uk/pk/)**

It is acting funny. I'm using the [easy slider 1.7](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) jquery plugin. In safari 4 (browser labs) **the slider div isn't centering up**. The css is as follows:

```
#slidercontainer{width:800px;padding:0;margin:0px auto;position:relative;}
```

I've tried:

```
#slidercontainer{width:800px;padding:0;margin:0 0 0 -400px;left:50%;position:relative;}
```

and still no luck, any ideas?

Also in safari 3 the div is even more messed up! I am starting to think it is the [jQuery plugin.](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)

---

My **second problem** is even more strange... almost. On the about and collection page in both safari 3 and 4 the background and border of the `#singlecol` div isn't showing!?

Here is my css:

```
#content #singlecol{padding:20px;background:#fff;border:#eb690b 1px solid;}
```

I have no idea what's going on, I have never had a problem with these browsers before and using Browserlabs is hard to see what's going wrong.

I was hoping someone could help me in the right direction? Is it because browserlabs is using the very basic versions i.e. 4.0.0 and 3.0.0 which are ridden with bugs?

Thanks!

p.s. I know lots of images and pages aren't working as I am still not finished :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out!

Basically for some reason safari 3 and 4 doesn't like it when you specify two css files with your styles for the main page across both, I was doing this to hep with caching and bandwidth naturally. So instead i have had to make a stylesheet for each page.

I suppose alternatively I could make one big stylesheet, which probably will work out more efficient still or just use php to generate the css!?

Comment: you should add comment rather then answer your own question, just a good practice.

I suggest having one single css, as per js you should do it too and if you can minify deployed instances of these files, you will save on request times. plus if you load one css file righ away, let say your initial load time might be hinder a bit, but rest of the page loads will increase. just a thought for your mind.